# How to show application name on first position of GridView

Tags: android

This is my example which show system install aplication names in `gridview`. But i want to show specific application name on top of `gridvew` what do i do? Below is my full source code that display selected apps in `listview` which names i provided  i just want to display this application 
`((p.packageName).equals("com.qurankarim.urdu"))`  on first position of `gridview` what do i do? please help me

```
                public class Learning extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

/* whether or not to include system apps */
private static final boolean INCLUDE_SYSTEM_APPS = false;

private ListView mAppsList;
private AppListAdapter mAdapter;
private List<App> mApps;
boolean isPressed = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.learning);

    final ImageButton Searchbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.poweron);
    Searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPressed) {
                Searchbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_off);
                finish();
            } else {
                Searchbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_on);
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed;

        }
    });


    GridView mAppsList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.appslist);

    // mAppsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.appslist);
    mAppsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mApps = loadInstalledApps(INCLUDE_SYSTEM_APPS);

    mAdapter = new AppListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    mAdapter.setListItems(mApps);
    mAppsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    new LoadIconsTask().execute(mApps.toArray(new App[] {}));
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    final App app = (App) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    String msg = "";
    builder.setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle(app.getTitle())
            .setIcon(mAdapter.getIcons().get(app.getPackageName()))
            .setPositiveButton("Launch",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void   
   onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // start the app by  
  invoking its launch intent
                            Intent i = 
  getPackageManager()

   .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                             app.getPackageName());
                            try {
                                if (i != null) {

    startActivity(i);
                                } else {
                                    i = new 

   Intent(app.getPackageName());

   startActivity(i);
                                }
                            } catch 
   (ActivityNotFoundException err) {

   Toast.makeText(Learning.this,

  "Error launching app",

   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void 
   onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}


 private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
    List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();


    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = p.applicationInfo;

        if (   ((p.packageName).equals("com.qurankarim.urdu"))
                || ((p.packageName) 
   .equals("appinventor.ai_hamada_yousef_o.MP3Quruan_2"))
                || 
   ((p.packageName).equals("biz.binzrysolution.qibla"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.EaseApps.duasof"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.EaseApps.hajj"))
                || ((p.packageName)

  .equals("com.HatafSoft.sahihmuslim_eng_free"))
                || 
  ((p.packageName).equals("com.aliftek.quran_urdu"))
                || 
  ((p.packageName).equals("com.amirmemon.quizgame.quran"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.baqa.quran.fehmulquran"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.baqa.quran.tafheemulquran"))
                || ((p.packageName)

 .equals("com.bitsmedia.android.muslimpro"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.chaks.duaas"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.chaks.quran"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.guidedways.iQuran"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.guidedways.iQuranPro"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.hajjguide.se.android"))
                || 
 ((p.packageName).equals("com.iroshni.asanquran"))
                 || ((p.packageName).equals("com.osama.maher"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.osama.sodesEn"))
                || 
   ((p.packageName).equals("com.perfection.WWWislan"))
                || 
  ((p.packageName).equals("com.quran.labs.androidquran"))

                || 
   ((p.packageName).equals("com.triosLabs.SahihMuslim"))
                || 
    ((p.packageName).equals("com.triosLabs.hadithreader"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.wAllahsWord"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("com.yallasoft.quran"))
                ||  
   ((p.packageName).equals("com.yaz.sahihMuslimOne"))
                || 
  ((p.packageName).equals("com.zx.AlQuran_karim_Free"))
                ||     
   ((p.packageName).equals("com.zx.Alquran_uthmanic_Free"))
                || 
    ((p.packageName).equals("excelarz.apps.dhqReader"))
                || 
   ((p.packageName).equals("io.vov.android.vitamio.demo"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("islam3d.liveWPcube"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("mydotdev.quranurdu"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("net.xbound.zakirnaik"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("q.and.u"))
                || ((p.packageName).equals("sadaqa.app.deentv"))
                || 
      ((p.packageName).equals("com.verypositive.Quran"))

        ) {


            App app = new App();
            app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                    .toString());
            app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
            app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
            app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
            CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo
                    .loadDescription(packageManager);
            app.setDescription(description != null ? 
  description.toString()
                    : "");
            apps.add(app);
            // }
        }
    }
    return apps;
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task to load the icons of the installed applications.
 */
private class LoadIconsTask extends AsyncTask<App, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(App... apps) {

        Map<String, Drawable> icons = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
        PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageManager();

        for (App app : apps) {
            String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
            Drawable ico = null;
            try {
                Intent i = 
   manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
                if (i != null) {
                    ico = manager.getActivityIcon(i);
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to find icon for package '"
                        + pkgName + "': " + 
   e.getMessage());
            }
            icons.put(app.getPackageName(), ico);
        }
        mAdapter.setIcons(icons);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

 }





                         public class AppListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

  private List<App> mApps;
  /** a map which maps the package name of an app to its icon drawable */
   private Map<String, Drawable> mIcons;
    private Drawable mStdImg;

 /**
  * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param context the application context which is needed for the layout inflater
 */
 public AppListAdapter(Context context) {
  // cache the LayoutInflater to avoid asking for a new one each time
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

  // set the default icon until the actual icon is loaded for an app
  mStdImg = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
 }

 @Override
  public int getCount() {
  return mApps.size();
  }

 @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
  return mApps.get(position);
  }

  @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  AppViewHolder holder;
  if(convertView == null) {
     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

     // creates a ViewHolder and stores a reference to the children view we want to    
   bind data to
     holder = new AppViewHolder();
     holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apptitle);
     holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appicon);
     convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else { 
     // reuse/overwrite the view passed assuming(!) that it is castable!
     holder = (AppViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  App app = mApps.get(position);

  holder.setTitle(app.getTitle());
  if (mIcons == null || mIcons.get(app.getPackageName()) == null) {
     holder.setIcon(mStdImg);
  } else {
     holder.setIcon(mIcons.get(app.getPackageName()));
  }

  return convertView; 
}


 public void setListItems(List<App> list) { 
  mApps = list; 
 }


 public void setIcons(Map<String, Drawable> icons) {
  this.mIcons = icons;
 }

/**
 * Returns the map containing the icons for each displayed app.
 * 
* @return a map which contains a mapping of package names to icon drawable for all  
  displayed apps
 */
  public Map<String, Drawable> getIcons() {
  return mIcons;
  }

 /**
 * A view holder which is used to re/use views inside a list.
 */
  public class AppViewHolder {

  private TextView mTitle;
  private ImageView mIcon;

  /**
   * Sets the text to be shown as the app's title
   * 
   * @param title the text to be shown inside the list row
   */
  public void setTitle(String title) {
     mTitle.setText(title);
  }

  /**
   * Sets the icon to be shown next to the app's title
   * 
   * @param img the icon drawable to be displayed
   */
  public void setIcon(Drawable img) {
     if (img != null) {
        mIcon.setImageDrawable(img);
     }
  }
  }
   }






                 public class App {

private String title;
private String packageName;
private String versionName;
private int versionCode;
private String description;

// ordinary getters and setters

public String getTitle() {
  return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
  this.title = title;
}

public String getPackageName() {
  return packageName;
}

public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
  this.packageName = packageName;
}

public String getVersionName() {
   return versionName;
}

public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
  this.versionName = versionName;
}

public int getVersionCode() {
   return versionCode;
}

public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
   this.versionCode = versionCode;
}

public String getDescription() {
  return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to recreate another List then add the rest of applications.
You can do something like this:

```
List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

for(PackageInfo package : packs) {
    String name = package.packageName;
    if("com.baqa.quran.tafheemulquran".equals(name)) { // Add other "equals" here
        App app = new App(); // Create your App […]
        apps.add(app);
        packs.remove(package);
    }
}

for(PackageInfo package : packs) {
    App app = new App(); // Create your App […]
    apps.add(app);
}
```